# Scraping data from an internally-called AJAX address

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get leagues data from this address:

http://www.10bet.com/sports/soccer/?utm_source=shp&utm_medium=sleft&utm_campaign=soccer

In that page, if you click on "Champions League" for example, in Firebug I see an AJAX call to this address:

http://www.10bet.com/pagemethods.aspx/GetLeaguesContent

The result is a JSON object which contains matches info from that league. However, when I get that page with cURL, even when I post exact parameters, I get a bunch of JavaScript code:

```
$url = 'http://www.10bet.com/pagemethods.aspx/GetLeaguesContent';
$fields = array(    
        'BranchID' => urlencode('1') , 
        'LeaguesCollection' => urlencode('10098') , 
                );

$fields_string  = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: yes, and? many, if not most/all, ajax calls are going to expect a JSON response...

Comment: They could easily be checking the origin of ajax calls (there are several Request headers they might be checking) and not return the same JSON data for offsite or direct calls to that URL. Plenty of sites take measures to prevent exactly what you're trying to do: unauthorized scraping of their data.

Comment: @MarcB i know , i love json responses ! , i'm saying when i call the exact address instead of that json response io get bunch of none sense javascript code

Comment: Try asking the site's admin. And if they tell you the information isn't available externally, well, then it's not.

Comment: @jszobody i dont' think that's the case here , if they wanted to do that the wouldn't go in trouble of responsing that amount of code back ... they would say some thing like access denied or nothing .

Comment: @max You're making an assumption. You really don't know do you? you can see in the ajax call that it is POSTing to variables. Create a simple HTML form that posts the same two variables to that URL.

Comment: @jszobody if you look at my code ,  i'm posting those variables with curl

Comment: @max I understand that. And you see the result you're getting isn't what their own ajax calls get. I suggest the HTML form as another way to quickly show that this site is not letting you do what you want, it's not a problem with your code from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a quick look and I was able to discover the problem in about a minute. It's a missing request header. I'm not going to tell you which one but I will tell you how I discovered it so next time you can do it yourself.

First, install Charles proxy and run it. Open that page in Chrome. When the browser makes the request it will show up in Charles.

Now highlight the request in question and go down to 'Edit' on the right click menu. Just start removing the headers that you think might be the problem one at a time and re-execute the request. When it sends the javascript, you will know that the last header you removed was the one.

Comment: thanx , i'm having problem with charls proxy (i'm living in one of those country s with awful internet filtering and proxys are banned) , but i got the ajax call headers from firebug and trying to send them all with my request ... it's not the damn gzip is it ?

Comment: Your country isn't banning proxies. Your ISP maybe. You need to solve this yourself though, or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: nope , im in iran right now ... all proxy apps and most of websites are  banned , maybe by isp but it's the government who tells them that .
anyway i got all headers from firebug and i think it's the `Content-Type : application/json` ... right now i'm trying to send headers with cur which is tricky

Comment: The proxy happens locally, so Iran won't know about it. Just try it, it's really the only help you're going to get for this.

Comment: thanx for your help ,i don't know who has given you the vote down but but s/he should stop doing that .